# Why does $\overbrace{\star\star}^{m}$ cause a double superscript error?

Tags: superscripts

In part of my HW paper I have:

```
$\overbrace{\star\star}^{m}$
```

This causes the following error:

```
! Double superscript.
\star ->^
         *
l.153          $\overbrace{\star\star}
                                      ^{m}$
```

If I change the line to `$\overbrace{\star}^{m}$` it works fine.  Why does the double `\star\star` cause the double superscript error, and how to fix it?!

FYI, This is what I'm trying to recreate:

[image]

Comment: Did you forget a begin{document} before it?

Comment: Nope...The template file that I'm using was given to us by the professor, so all the boilerplate is there.  These are the packages that are being used: \usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,enumerate,amsthm}
\usepackage{zed-csp}.

Comment: The problem is with the `zed-csp` package. It defines `\star` as `^*`

Comment: By the way, the symbol in your image is `\ast`, not `\star`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is arising because of the `zed-csp` file which redefines `\star` as

```
\def\star{^*}
```

If you feel you must use the `zed-csp` package, then before calling this package you can write:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\oldstar\star
\usepackage{zed-csp}
```

Then later you should be able to write

```
$\overbrace{\oldstar\oldstar}^{m}$
```

However, it seems from the image you've posted it is `\ast` that you want to use instead of `\star`.

If you decide you do not intend to use the redefined `\star` from the `zed-csp` package you can do something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\let\oldstar\star
\usepackage{zed-csp}
\let\zedstar\star
\let\star\oldstar

\begin{document}

$\overbrace{\star\star}^{m}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome!  I think in future classes we will need zed-csp, so I just replaced all \star with \ast and everything is perfect.  I will accept this as the answer when the system allows me to.